# How to detect if pdf is scanned or generated through a tool

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, pdf-generation, ocr

I am working on a product where we accept input as the pdf file. We read the content of pdf through a third party API. These API fails if pdf is a scanned file or has copy restriction; API not providing these details in output.

Is there any way in C# I can detect if the PDF is scanned file on a normal one? So, I can show the user an appropriate message.

I am using c# and also using ABCPDF.

Comment: How about using that third party API at PDF upload time? If it fails, report to uploader that his PDF is not good for the purpose.

Comment: Texhnically there *is* no difference between a scanned PDF and a "normal" one (there is nothing abnormal about a scanned PDF). Have you considered just checking if there is text inside?

Answer (score 0):

To see if a page has any text you could use the Doc.GetText method (and test the length of the string it returns). Or for a more sophisticated approach, try the [TextOperation](https://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/default.htm?page=source/8-abcpdf.operations/8-textoperation/default.htm) class.

For images, you could count the images on a page with code like this:

```
    doc.PageNumber = 2;
    ImageOperation op = new ImageOperation(doc);
    op.PageContents.AddPages(doc.PageNumber);
    IList<ImageProperties> images = op.GetImageProperties();
```

Then check if images.Count is zero.

In terms of copy restrictions, if you try and read a password-protected PDF without supplying a password, ABCpdf will throw an exception. Which you can catch :)

Otherwise ABCpdf applies and respects PDF permissions as required by Adobe. You can set/get them using the [Doc.Encyption](https://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/default.htm?page=source/5-abcpdf/doc/2-properties/encryption.htm) property. [I am affiliated with ABCpdf.]

Answer (score -1):

You can check the content of each page of the document. A scanned document contains only objects which type is Image, whereas a "normal" PDF contains text objects and others.
Here is a sample code with the Patagames PDF SDK. But your API probably has an analog

```
        PdfCommon.Initialize();

        using (var doc = PdfDocument.Load(@"d:\1\Europa Service Karte.pdf"))
        {
            foreach(var page in doc.Pages)
            {
                foreach(var obj in page.PageObjects)
                {
                    if(!(obj is PdfImageObject))
                    {
                        return; //this is a "normal" pdf;
                    }
                }
            }
            //there is no any page with non image objects
            //so it is a scanned PDF
        }
```

Comment: shame this is a commercial library